# Beginner's Guide to Setting Up Qt for C++

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt, installation

I'm interested in playing around with GUIs and I've been trying to set up Qt for Visual Studio 2008 and MinGW but have failed miserably—in that at times I'd compile the library and it still wouldn't work and others the compile would fail. Can anyone recommend a good guide to set up Qt (or another GUI toolkit if setting up Qt just doesn't work well for beginners). No preference for IDE really, just want to start coding already :)

**Edit** I tried both answers and they were both great, the QtCreator is a fast way to get started with Qt. And 20th Century Boy's blogpost was a thorough guide to setting up Qt with VS08 that I could even follow (answering the original question). Thanks and happy coding :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have covered Qt and VS 2008 integration in my blog. Have a look at it here...
http://cplusplus-mortals.blogspot.com/2009/04/qt-part-3-configuration-for-visual.html

Comment: The guide says "3. Select the checkbox to download and install MinGW - it is needed for the build process." which is actually not true - MinGW is not needed to build Qt with VC++.

Comment: I tried compiling without mingw and it failed during the configure phase. I could only get it to work by installing mingw.

Answer (score 7):

[Qt Creator](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/developer-tools) is probably the most straightforward way to get started with Qt.

Answer (score 1):

[Installing Qt on Windows](http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/install-win.html) describes all the needed steps. Which of the steps failed for you?

Comment: Your link is dead :( Probably -- http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/install-win.html,

Comment: That was almost 4 years ago, Qt changed owners 2 times since then.